# Blurry Numbers in Word 2013

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word-2013

When printing a Document in Word 2013 to PDF (Adobe PDF Printer coming with Acrobat X Pro) or paper chapter numbers get blurred quiet badly. Doing so with Word 2010 on the same Win 7 PC the numbers are fine. Font is Calibri at the moment but this also happens with Arial, TNR, etc. If i use the export function (create pdf/xps) i get the same bad result.

Does anybody know what's wrong here?

[image: Comparision]

Comment: Are you printing form Word 2010 and 2013 from the same computer?  If not, are both computers running the same version of Windows?

Comment: What PDF printer do you use? What happens when you SAVE the document as a PDF using word 2013?  I could be some kind of processing error depending on the PDF printer driver or the postscript processing. Because you are using different Word Versions there are as well may be different print processing steps before the document is printed by the pdf printer.

Comment: @IvanViktorovic - I use Adobe Acrobat plugin to print to PDF and still face the problem with Arial font - I've not tried Calibri though

Comment: Do you get the same result when you save the document to PDF?

Comment: Edited my question with concern to yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know the reason as to why this happens. It happens to me as well when I use Arial font in Word 2013 when I use the Words' in-built feature to save file as PDF.

There is a workaround for this - but not a solution that I know of.
When you save as PDF - Click on Options - and select ISO 19005_1 compliant PDF/A under the PDF options.
[image]

*Note: Selecting this option made the resulting PDF as "un-commentable" - which means if I request someone to review my document, the reviewer cannot post stickys' or draw shapes available under the Adobe Acrobat Commenting tool bar*